# 1c автоматическое генерирование файлов xml

Tags: 1с

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь по автоматическому генирированию файлов, для загрузки на сайт Import.xml(Товар и описание) offers.xml(Количество, цены). Как-то можно это сделать средствами самой 1с предприятие ?

Answer (score 1):

Находится же за 1 запрос в google https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=42&LESSON_ID=6318

Comment: Вы мне показываете связь между 1c-bitrix и 1c-предприятие.

Comment: да. Разница там в 1 параметре "Выгружать в отдельный xml" или как то так. Там про это будет написано при описании параметров

Comment: Можешь создать пакетXDTO и создавать объектыXDTO и выгружать через ФабрикаXDTO.ЗаписатьXML(<ЗаписьXML>, <Элемент>,

Comment: Это сложно - там 100% путь есть легче. Я помню, что выгрузка из bitrix на выгрузку в файл переключается 1 галкой. Главное не забыть выгрузить справочники.